# Solution: NoClassDefFoundError when dynamically compiling code

Tags: java, reflection, compilation

Simply put, I had this working:

```
java -cp ".:bin:MyJar.jar" path.to.My.Main
```

but this threw an exception when trying to load a dynamically compiled class:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

The failure was on

```
x = clazz.newInstance();
```

Where I get a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:". I loaded the class using a custom class loader, since the class was runtime compiled. The reason the exception was occurring was because java was using a separate classloader when trying to load imports inside the clazz. This is rectified by modifying your ClassLoader extends URLClassLoader to call super.loadClass(className, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in Question:

Modify your custom classloader to call super.loadClass(). Even though the stack trace may not obviously pass through your classloader.

Comment: Class.forName("", true, customLoader);